# Android : Which method is called when fragment is pop out from backstack

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions

I have researched on stack overflow but doesn't seem to find solution.

I have one mainActivity and several frgaments, I am doing fragment transaction by 
`replace` method and corresponding fragment added to backstack, but my problem is when I pop it out from back stack which callback is called I want to check something before pop it out from stack, onResume() method is not calling when I pop it from back stack

HELP

Comment: check the fragment life cycle http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do the following:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener()
    {
        public void onBackStackChanged() 
        {                   
            // Your logic here               
        }
    });
```

This callback will be called upon each change on the back stack - even when a fragment is added. If you want to know when a fragment was removed then add the following logic

```
Fragment someFragment = (Fragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentItem);

if (someFragment == null) {
   // this fragment was removed from back stack
}
```

Comment: but it is also called when fragment is first initialized WHY?

Comment: @thanx Marky
I am wondering it is better to define above method in activity or fragment ?

Comment: Your Activity for sure

Comment: I have implemented this method in onCreate() of activity but it is showing uneven behaviour

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83948/discussion-between-markysmarky-and-ravi).

Comment: finally I found out solution... Thanx for help

Comment: checkout my new question and plz solve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565364/android-hiding-action-bar-in-fragment

Comment: addOnBackStackChangedListener is called when the back stack change!, so, whether addBackStack or popBackStack will trigger this event..