# Android : Hiding action bar in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, fragment

I have 2 Fragments `mainFragment` and `childFragment`. I want to show actionbar in `mainFragment` but wants to hide in `childFragment`. All is working fine except that when I comes back to `mainFragment` from `childFragment` and again goes to `childFragment` action bar shows for seconds before get hidden ..

I don't know why ?
HELP

In `childFragment` I am doing this

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
    mainActivity.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                // handle back button's click listener

                mainActivity.onBackPressed();
                ((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show();
                mainActivity.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you share your code of your fragment layouts and the code of hiding the `ActionBar`?

Answer (score 0):

You should handle all transitions in your main activity...  There you should handle all the logic according to your needs - such as hiding/showing the action bar and such...

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in your fragmen's onActivityCreated method:

```
((ActionBarActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();
mainActivity.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
```

Edit:
I assume that you are handling your fragment transactions in your activity. Before you replace your fragment in activity with:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout, new YourFragment()).commit();
```

do your actionbar hide and show operations according to which fragment you are replacing. (main or child)

Comment: i suggested another solution and edited my answer. If it still not working you can try to use toolbar. If you need some help about how to use toolbar let me know and i can edit my answer again.